# Possible to update TRecord member by name

Tags: delphi, rtti

Is it possible to have a get and set value for TMyRecord when you have the name of the record member?  something similar to `RTTI`.

I cannot use an array as the members may have different data types.

type

```
TMyRecord = record
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer; 
  Z: DateTime;
end;

var MyRecord: TMyRecord;

procedure UpdateValue(aRecordMemberName: string; AValue: Integer);
begin
  MyRecord[aRecordmemberName] := AValue;
end;

function GetValue(aRecordMemberName: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := MyRecord[aRecordmemberName];
end;

procedure Main();
begin 
  SetValue('X', 5);
  showmessage( GetValue('Y').ToString );
end;
```

On an additional note, is it possible to iterate through all members of a `Record`, similar to iterating through `TFields` or `TFieldDefs`?

thanks.

- Using Delphi 11 in Firemonkey

Comment: "I cannot use an array as the members may have different data types." You can. Use `Variant` as the data type. It almost appears like you need a `TDictionary<string, Variant>`.

Comment: You can do it with RTTI. But there are other options too. How many different record types do you want to do this with.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for the quick reply.  ok, in my case, say if I wish to use it as record as I need multiple instances of it, would the above be possible with a TRecord?  It almost seems "nothing is [quite] impossible" in Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan probably 4 main types such as Cardinal, Integer, TDateTime and string.

Comment: Yes, almost anything is possible, but in my experience, people are often too eager to resort to RTTI. In *most* cases, there are far better solutions.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I didn't consider a TDictionary<string, Variant> because there are a fixed number of variables in the app in this situation while I usually reserve TDictionary for situations where number of variants are dynamic and is determined at run-time.  Is using rtti a bad idea?

Comment: (Also, please note that there is no such thing as `TRecord`.)

Comment: RTTI is a bit complicated (meaning that you need to write many lines of code) and rather slow. Sure, it will probably be fast enough in your case, so it will probably be good enough. But it isn't ideal. // If you have a fixed number of fields of different types, it is somewhat strange that you need to access these by string names. // A `TDictionary<string, Variant>` makes sense even if there is a fixed number of elements. Of course, you can also use a static array of `Variant`. Or you could create an enumerated type `TFrogProperty = (fpName, fpBirthday, fpWeight)` with a record helper ...

Comment: ... making it possible to write `fpName.ToString` and `TFrogProperty.FromString("Name")`. Then you can have a static array indexed by this enum: `Properties: array[TFrogProperty] of Variant`. But remember that using strings like this partly replaces compile-time error checking (good) with run-time error checking (less good).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand ok thanks for the pointer.  oh I didn't know I can write fpName.ToString and .FromString directly even though I have used a static array indexed by enum.  would you be able to post it as a short answer with a short example of the .ToString and FromString part so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: type TMyOptions = ( mo1, mo2, mo3 );  const ARRAY_MYOPTIONS : array[TMyOptions] of Variant = ( 0, 0, 0 );  - error Class does not have a default property. i have used array of string before with no issues. array of variant gives error.

Comment: No, I asked how many different record types do you want to do this with. I still don't really understand what the motivation is, and it is quite possible that you are attacking the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan apologies, I may understood the question wrongly.  only one record type, ie. TMyRecord that has 4 types of datatypes string, cardinal, integer and datetime.

Comment: RTTI seems like overkill. Why do you need to access by name anyway? And how are you going to get over the fact that the values that come back have different types? I mean what do you expect `GetValue(aRecordMemberName: string): Integer` do return for all the fields that are not integers?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i was planning to add overload functions for GetValue for other data types, but will use variant instead. i don't need to access by name, by a enumerator type is fine.  yes, agree, now it seems RTTI seems overkill - unless I have many different Record types to deal with ?

Comment: @PeterJones: It is not possible to overload functions based only on return type.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand oh yes, my bad... thanks for the note.  Once again, thanks for the elegant piece of code! Programming can indeed be an art as much as a science.

Comment: If you want the features of a TDataset then it might be easier to just use one. Lots of in memory TDataSet components available.

Comment: @Brian thanks but I prefer a TRecord in this case. simpler to manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of fields of different types, it is somewhat strange that you need to access these by string names. Still, let's assume this is the right thing to do.

RTTI is a bit complicated (meaning that you need to write "many" lines of code) and rather slow. Sure, it will probably be fast enough in your case, so it will probably be good enough. But it isn't ideal.

In my experience, people are often too eager to resort to RTTI. In most cases, there are better solutions.

One non-RTTI solution would be to use a `TDictionary<string, Variant>`.

Another would be like this:

```pascal
type
  EFrogException = class(Exception);
  TFrogProperty = (fpName, fpBirthDate, fpWeight);
  TFrogPropertyHelper = record helper for TFrogProperty
  strict private
    const PropNames: array[TFrogProperty] of string = ('Name', 'Birth date', 'Weight');
  public
    function ToString: string;
    class function FromString(const APropName: string): TFrogProperty; static;
  end;

  TFrog = record
  strict private
    FProperties: array[TFrogProperty] of Variant;
  private
    function GetProp(Prop: TFrogProperty): Variant;
    procedure SetProp(Prop: TFrogProperty; const Value: Variant);
    function GetPropByName(APropName: string): Variant;
    procedure SetPropByName(APropName: string; const Value: Variant);
  public
    property Prop[Prop: TFrogProperty]: Variant read GetProp write SetProp;
    property PropByName[Prop: string]: Variant read GetPropByName write SetPropByName; default;
  end;
```

where

```pascal
{ TFrogPropertyHelper }

class function TFrogPropertyHelper.FromString(
  const APropName: string): TFrogProperty;
begin
  for var Prop := Low(TFrogProperty) to High(TFrogProperty) do
    if SameText(Prop.ToString, APropName) then
      Exit(Prop);
  raise EFrogException.CreateFmt('Invalid frog property: "%s".', [APropName]);
end;

function TFrogPropertyHelper.ToString: string;
begin
  if InRange(Ord(Self), Ord(Low(TFrogProperty)), Ord(High(TFrogProperty))) then
    Result := PropNames[Self]
  else
    Result := '';
end;

{ TFrog }

function TFrog.GetProp(Prop: TFrogProperty): Variant;
begin
  Result := FProperties[Prop];
end;

function TFrog.GetPropByName(APropName: string): Variant;
begin
  Result := Prop[TFrogProperty.FromString(APropName)];
end;

procedure TFrog.SetProp(Prop: TFrogProperty; const Value: Variant);
begin
  FProperties[Prop] := Value;
end;

procedure TFrog.SetPropByName(APropName: string; const Value: Variant);
begin
  Prop[TFrogProperty.FromString(APropName)] := Value;
end;
```

Then you can do things like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var James: TFrog;

  James['Name'] := 'James';
  James['Birth date'] := EncodeDate(2016, 05, 10);
  James['Weight'] := 2.4;

  ShowMessage(James['Name']);

  James['Name'] := 'Sir James';
  ShowMessage(James['Name']);

  // And you can still be type safe if you want to:

  James.Prop[fpName] := 'Sir James Doe';
  ShowMessage(James.Prop[fpName]);

end;
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed example.  would the best way to implement a output to string be in function TFrog.GetAllProperties: string;
begin 
  for var Prop := Low(TFrogProperty) to High(TFrogProperty) do Result := Result + self.Prop[Prop] + #13#10;
end;

Comment: @PeterJones: I didn't understand that. `Result := Result` seems like a NOP.

Comment: sorry, typed half-way and accidentally hit Enter key.  and in GetAllProperties, how do I detect the variant is TDateTime so I can do some special date format...

Comment: Have a look at [`VarType`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Variants.VarType). Or you could extend the `TFrogPropertyHelper` with a `PropType` function, with a custom `TPropType = (ptText, ptInteger, ptFloat, ptDate)` that suits your own needs.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the above TPropType function but  you have gotten me to a very good start! much appreciated. will post again if I encounter any problems.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Why `Variant` rather than `TValue`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No major reason.